# Multiple Sound Device Ordering Not Always Working

Tags: usb, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I’m running Ubuntu Studio 18.04, PA with ALSA and trying to control the loading sequence of multiple devices.  I've added to the end of my /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf the following:

`options snd_virtuoso id=DX index=0 #vid=0x13f6 pid=0x8788 # Xonar DX
options snd_hda_intel id=Generic index=1 vid=0x10de pid=0x0fba # Realtek On-board
options snd_hda_intel id=NVidia index=2 vid=0x1022 pid=0x1457 # HDMI
options snd-usb-audio index=3 vid=0x046d pid=0x082d # Webcam C920 Mic
options snd-usb-audio index=4 vid=0x0d8c pid=0x0005 # Snowball Mic
options snd-usb-audio index=5 vid=0x1235 pid=0x8016 # Focusrite Scarlett 2i2
options snd-usb-audio index=6 vid=0x0d8c pid=0x0004 # Modi Multibit`

I’ve also blacklisted the USB and HDMI devices in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf to prevent udev from loading them before alsa-base.conf has a chance to work:

`snd_hda_intel
snd_usb_audio`

The problem is that 1 out of every 4 or 5 reboots the USB device being instructed to load at index 5 will instead load at index 0. I’ve verified the vid and pid a half dozen times. At this point the Xonar DX doesn't load at all and leaves index 5 unused.

The last thing I tryied was to set USB and HDMI indices to -2 in the alsa-base.config but that didn’t help either:

`options snd_usb_audio index=-2
options snd_hda_intel index=-2`

I’m no Linux master, just reading what others have done. Any ideas on something I may have missed to allow my Xonar DX to always load at index 0 would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`modprobe` allows only a single `options` line for each module; a later line will just replace an earlier line.

If one module handles multiple cards, you have to give all options at once:

```perl
options snd_virtuoso id=DX index=0  # Xonar DX
options snd_hda_intel id=Generic,NVidia index=1,2  # Realtek On-board, HDMI
options snd-usb-audio index=3,4,5,6 vid=0x046d,0x0d8c,0x1235,0x0d8c pid=0x082d,0x0005,0x8016,0x0004
# Webcam C920 Mic, Snowball Mic, Focusrite Scarlett 2i2, Modi Multibit
```

And only USB devices have PID/VID values.

Comment: You, my sir, are awesome. Works great and thank you very much.